# Find all unique single branch on a tree in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write an algorithm in Python to get a list of all nodes in a tree where the path reaches until the last node.

Each child has an unknown number of children. It is a representation of a comment thread. For instance the for post A there are replies B and C and so on. I want to get all unique streams of conversation so just get the body of the text from each node: eg: (A B D G). So the data frame would have the following rows: 0(A B D G), 1(A B D H), 2(A C E I), 3(A C F), 4(A C J).

```
       A
       |
     -----
    |     |
    B     C
    |     |
    |    -------
    |   |   |.  |
    D   E   F.   J
  / |   |
 G  H   I
```

This the tree I currently have

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def add_child (self, child):
        child.parent = self 
        self.children.append(child)

    def get_children_body(self):
        body=""
        for child in self.children:
            body=body+child.data["body"]
        return body
    
    def has_children(self):
        return len(self.children)>0

    def get_author(self):
        return self.data["author"]
```

Edit: this does not work but this is something I have tried

```
#returns list of list
def find_all_branches(node):
    retList=[]
    for child in node.children:
        retList.append(find_all_branches_recursive(child,[node.data],retList))

    return retList

def find_all_branches_recursive(node,curr_list,final_list):
    if node.has_children():
        for child in node.children:
            curr_list.append(child.data)
            find_all_branches_recursive(child,curr_list,final_list)
    else:
        curr_list.append(node.data)
        final_list.append(curr_list)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: To put it another way, for each leaf in the tree, you want a list of all nodes from the root to that leaf.  Have you tried to code it?

Comment: Sounds like it should be a simple depth-first search.

Comment: I am new to using python and I primarily use R for statistics for my research so I am little unfamiliar with computer science I'm sorry. could you please help me with coding as what I tried does not seem to work.

Comment: Please share what you tried - even if it doesn't work, it will give people trying to provide an answer a good idea of what solution you were going for and what needs explaining here. StackOverflow isn't here to write working solutions for you, but a working solution may well be a part of an answer to explain why your solution didn't work.

Comment: btw, it is quite polite to provide the code that generates your sample data structure, so helpers don't have to type tons of repetitve lines to create that particular tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple enough generator function:

```
def paths(node):
    if node.children:
        for child in node.children:
            for path in paths(child):
                yield [node.data] + path
    else:
        yield [node.data]

>>> list(paths(a))  # a being the root node of your tree
[['A', 'B', 'D', 'G'], 
 ['A', 'B', 'D', 'H'], 
 ['A', 'C', 'E', 'I'], 
 ['A', 'C', 'F'], 
 ['A', 'C', 'J']]
```